# Evaluate json file | Python Crawler

Tags: python

I would like to evaluate the Json file in order to be able to access the individual keys / values.

i get the error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ResultSet

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import json
url1 ="https://www.willhaben.at/iad/gebrauchtwagen/motorrad/ktm-motorrad/790"
r = requests.get(url1, verify=False)
```

.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

liste = doc.find_all("script", type='application/ld+json')
print(liste)

json_object = json.loads(liste)
print(json_object)
```

Output:

```
[<script type="application/ld+json"> 
{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","itemListElement": 
[{"@type":"ListItem","position":0,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-ktm-790-duke- 
445152541/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790- 
445095298/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"url":"/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790- 
adventure-r-444847161/"} ......

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ResultSet
```

Comment: You have to extract valid JSON in text form in order to parse it. The result of a `find_all()` is not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 json documents that match the filter. The same process is used to parse them.

```
>>> type(liste)
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
>>> type(liste[0])
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> d = json.loads(liste[0].string)
>>> d
{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'ItemList', 'itemListElement': [{'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 0, 'url': '/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-ktm-790-duke-445152541/'}, {'@type': 'ListItem', 'position': 1, 'url': '/iad/gebrauchtwagen/d/motorrad/ktm-790-445095298/'}.....
```

You could loop to create a list of parsed documents:

```
>>> documents = [json.loads(e.string) for e in liste]
```